# JFrame/Panel not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I should be displaying a row of 2 buttons but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Studying extends JFrame{

JButton button = new JButton("Word");
JButton button1 = new JButton("MoreWords");

public void Studying(){

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
p1.add(button);
p1.add(button1);
add(p1);

}

 public static void main(String[] args){
Studying frame = new Studying();
frame.setTitle("test");
frame.setSize(500,200);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The constructor is not an actual constructor, it is being treated as a method, causing the classes default constructor to be used. Constructors do not specify a return type, even `void`.

**Fixed Constructor**

```
public Studying(){

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    p1.add(button);
    p1.add(button1);
    add(p1);

}
```

Comment: Wow... why did I put that there, I've made A LOT of GUI, but, it was invisible to me.

Comment: @Corjava Happens to everyone.  Take a break if you need it. I always mix up `=` and `==` when I am tired.

Comment: Yeah, finals week... just practicing GUI for it.

Answer (score 0):

The function Studying() isn't a class, so `Studying frame = new Studying();` refers to `public class Studying extends JFrame` and `public void Studying()` is never called. Move the creation of the buttons to the static main, and append them to the frame, and the buttons will be visible.

```
public class Studying extends JFrame {

static JButton button = new JButton("Word");
static JButton button1 = new JButton("MoreWords");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Studying frame = new Studying();
    frame.setTitle("test");
    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Studying extends JFrame{

JButton button = new JButton("Word");
JButton button1 = new JButton("MoreWords");

public Studying(){

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
p1.add(button);
p1.add(button1);
add(p1);

}

 public static void main(String[] args){
Studying frame = new Studying();
frame.setTitle("test");
frame.setSize(500,200);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

}
```